# How to fix alignment problem in git log --graph

Tags: git, pretty-print, text-alignment

I'm using the following alias to render my git commit history on console if no GUI is available:

```
$ git config alias.treex
log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(cyan)%h%Creset - %C(cyan)%ad%Creset %<(80,trunc)%s   %C(cyan)%>(20,trunc)%an - %Cgreen%>(12)%cr%Creset' --date=format:'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M' --abbrev-commit --all
```

While the format string uses align and fixed size string formats like `%<(80,trunc)%s`, the graph rendered by `git log --graph` destroys the alignment:

[image: Git treex result.]
(click to enlarge)

How to fix the broken alignment cause by the graph itself?

Comment: You cannot do this inside `git log` itself. You'll need to write your own program. Your best bet is to use `git log` or `git rev-list` to extract the data you would like to display, format it the way you want, and then display it. This is what `gitk` does, for instance, although it does it with a GUI using Tcl/TK; the same approach will work for text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `%<(80,trunc)%s` that tells `git log` to render the subject on 80 characters you can use `%<|(110,trunc)%s` that tells it to render the subject until it reaches the `110`<sup>th</sup> column of the output. This way the next field after the subject starts at the `111`<sup>st</sup> column and the order is restored. 
*(`110` is approximately the original `80` characters you want for the subject + the sizes of the columns before it (`%h` = `7` characters, `%ad` = `16` characters) and the delimiter characters you put between them.)*

Of course you can use a different value. You can also try to constraint the width of the first field (`%h`) to get all the other fields aligned but it won't align properly on the sections of the history that contain a lot of branches; the `%s` field is large and uses enough columns to accommodate two dozens of concurrent branches.

The format is described in the [documentation of `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) right under the `<()` format and it is present in all versions of the documentation page (that unfortunately starts with `2.3.8`). If you are using an older Git version, it is possible that the format is not available for you. The best advice in this situation is to update your Git to a more recent version.

Answer (score 4):

## Shifting the `%h` placeholder for alignment

As [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) previously mentionend you can constrain the width of the first field. For example, if you add `%>|(16)` to the beginning of your formatting definition you can shift the abbreviated commit hash (`%h`) to finish at least at the 16th column. If you subtract the 7 digits of `%h` and an additional whitespace character you will give the graph a scope of 8 digits.

Your original git log history format:
[image: Unaligned git log history]

A more aligned version by adding `%>|(16)` for `%h`:
[image: Aligned git log history]

## Adding a length argument

As [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) also mentioned, this solution will face a problem. Once your graph exceeds the lenght of 8 characters, due to a project containing many parallel branches, your log entries will get shifted even more. You would have to adjust your alias according to the current Git project situation. Luckily there is a [trick for powerful Git aliases](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/advanced-git-aliases). With this trick you can pass an argument to your alias that sets the number of shifted columns.

Calling your alias with the paramater `30` then shifts your Git log history entries by 22 columns:
[image: Aligned git log history with argument]

## Set a default value for the length argument

Now, it may not be your intention to pass the number of columns every single time you call your alias. This [link](https://jondavidjohn.com/git-aliases-parameters/) explains how to set a default parameter. This way your alias refers to the default value once called without an argument. Once we are at it, we can correct the deviation of 8 digits directly inside the alias. Thereby, the passed argument directly corresponds to the columns actually shifted.

## Final alias

Your final Git alias accepting an argument to shift the Git log entries by `x` columns with a default shift of 8 digits:

```
$ git config --global alias.treex
!f() { x=${1-16}; length=`expr $x + 8`; git log --color --graph --pretty=format:"%>|($length)%C(cyan)%h%Creset - %C(cyan)%ad%Creset %<(80,trunc)%s   %C(cyan)%>(20,trunc)%an - %Cgreen%>(12)%cr%Creset" --date=format:%d.%m.%Y; }; f
```